# Center div between two fixed divs

Tags: html, css

I have got two divs which are fixed to the left and the right edges.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="SideNav1">
    Side Menu1
</div>
<div class="SideNav2">
    Side Menu2
</div>
<div id="Middlediv ">
    Middle Div
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.SideNav1 {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 250px; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111; /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
}

.SideNav2 {
        height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
        width: 250px; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #111; /* Black*/
        overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    }
```

Now my goal is to have a third div alligning in the center of those two divs. I can't get it working. I tried something like this but it didn't work out:

```
#Middlediv {
    background-color: white;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the existing layout, I would use `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` to center the middle element. Also cleaned up your CSS.

```css
.SideNav1,
.SideNav2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.SideNav1 {
  left: 0;
}

.SideNav2 {
  right: 0;
}

#Middlediv {
  background-color: white;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="SideNav1">
    Side Menu1
</div>
<div class="SideNav2">
    Side Menu2
</div>
<div id="Middlediv">
    Middle Div
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where is the content of the middle div? I can't find it..

Comment: well you have `width: 400px` on the middle div and `width: 250px` on the side navs. So the window has to be `> 900px` for the full middle div to be visible.

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't appear still. I will adjust the middle one to 50px. So it should be exactly in the middle of those two, with the correct margins.

Comment: @Anokrize I changed it to 50px. Looks fine, but it looked fine before. does it look like this to you? http://i.imgur.com/eRnNMRf.png

Comment: Yes it works, sorry!! Didn't work in my jsFiddle somehow. Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVXEVW

One of the things screwing you up was a space in the div id "Middlediv ">. I also added an auto width and padding to the sides of the Middlediv.

**HTML**

```
<div class="SideNav1">
    Side Menu1
</div>
<div class="SideNav2">
    Side Menu2
</div>
<div id="Middlediv">
    Middle Div
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.SideNav1 {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 250px; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111; /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
}

.SideNav2 {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 250px; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111; /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
}

#Middlediv {
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 250px;
    padding-right: 250px;
}
```